# Time command 'time' in Ubuntu 14.04 refuses to print PM or AM

Tags: 14.04, time, locale

I want to print the time on the command line in this format:

**11:30 PM**

Then I type:

```
date +"%I:%M %p"
```

And the result is:

**11:30**

I try then:

```
date +"%p"
```

And the result is two blank spaces where PM should be.

Please see how beautifully my locale settings and KDE clock are set:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The behaviour of `%p` is locale-dependent. What does `locale` say?

Comment: @fkraiem Problem solved. The locale file in /etc/... was a mess, because I had initially installed Ubuntu while living in another country. And the KDE settings do not update the locale correctly, even when they show as if they had.

Comment: Great. It would be nice if you could write an answer describing how you solved the problem (and then accept it). SE doesn't like questions without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Someone wrote in a comment:

> The behaviour of %p is locale-dependent.

So I had a look at the file /etc/default/locale, and it was a mess. I had installed this Ubuntu in another country and later moved to the US. I had updated the locale settings with the KDE frontend, at least that is what I thought, but apparently the frontend does not work well and you have to go the old way editing ascii system files (better if using emacs or vi, in a cathode ray tube SVGA screen).

After changing all values to es_US and rebooting, it works fine.

Yeah, my answer is too crappy. I won't accept it, in case someone wants to step in and do it better. I am not very sure what I am talking about.

Comment: I never understand why they release a new Ubuntu every six months or one year or so, and "freeze" (stop maintaining except for security patches) the previous one. That way, there will never be a stable distribution. This issue (the frontend not doing what it says it does) is not new. Changing your user password for instance has to be done by console too, and not by the corresponding dialog in Settings, that doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to keep a stable install you should use a LTS version.

Comment: @Murphy That's what I am using, if you read the title of my question it says 14.04, which is an LTS version. But "stable" is just a name. It is plagued with small bugs like any other version. That's why it sucks that they freeze each version after a few months and go for the next one. And I prefer to forget the hell I had with 12.04 LTS and the random hangs. Stable my *ss. Still, it's way better than Windows and way cheaper than Mac, so we cope with it.